# Arrays syntax in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy

How to say in python "from the beginning of the array" and "all the array". For example if my code in Matlab is:

```
images(:, n) = img(:)
```

What is its equivalent in python?

Comment: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Comment: Are you using numpy? If you're coming from matlab, that's the package you should be looking at. Read a tutorial and your code will become `images[:, n] = img`.

Comment: @NPE: Much better reference. `array` is so often used when `list` is meant that I assumed the latter was meant.

Answer (score 1):

It is
`images[:,n] = img.ravel()`

Comment: it gives AttributeError: ravel

Comment: img must be an array, not a list

Comment: can u tell how to convert the list to an array?